# What is the difference if use Subject over a Get Service method in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a service and I have 2 solutions from this kind of problem and I want to know what is best and when to use the Subject solution above the Service solution.

I have a UserModel that all my components see with my service, the approach that I want is when I change the UserModel from service, changes it for all my application

## 1 FIRST SERVICE

```
export class UserService {

  private userModel: UserModel = new UserModel();

  public userSubject$ = new Subject<any>();

  private timeOut = 20000;
  private mainConfig: MainConfig;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.mainConfig = new MainConfig();
  }

  getUserModel() {
    return this.userModel;
  }

  setUserModel(user) {
    this.userModel = user
  }

}
```

And is just to make this call in my HTML from all my components and will work

```
this.userService.getUserModel().name
```

The second approach

## 2 SECOND SERVICE

```
  @Injectable()
    export class UserService {

      private userModel: UserModel = new UserModel();

      public userSubject$ = new Subject<any>();

      private timeOut = 20000;
      private mainConfig: MainConfig;

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.mainConfig = new MainConfig();
      }

      getUserModel() {
        return this.userModel;
      }

      setUserModel(user) {
        this.userSubject$.next(this.userModel = user);
      }

    }
```

And in my HTML file, I just use

```
{{ userModel.name }}
```

And I must make this new line on my example-component.ts

## ngOnInit

```
this.subTemp = this.userService.userSubject$.subscribe(
  user => this.userModel = user
);
```

## ngOnDestroy

```
this.subTemp.unsubscribed();
```

What is the advantage to make the Subject from direct from Service? Because I need to make much more work

Comment: If you ever wanted to do something in your component after your user model changed, how would you do it in the first approach?

Comment: This is a method call that you are doing explicitly `this.userService.getUserModel().name` whereas the other one is the framework doing it for you. The second approach I recommend based on my understanding.

Comment: @AlbertoRivera just using this  this.userService.setUserModel(user)

Comment: @wavrik yes you'll get that user data the first time, but then your component will not know that the model has changed afterwards using the first approach.

Comment: @callback my service is a provider that I put in app.module.ts it is a Singleton, so in all my components in HTML I just put this this.userService.getUserModel().name, so when you make this function this.userService.setUserModel(user), all my components change without using a subscribe approach.

Answer (score 0):

What you wish to know is the difference between **pull** based method vs **push** based method of retrieving data.

#### Method 1: pull based

As the name suggests the **pull** based method is traditional method where you for eg. call a function and it returns the value once. If you need the value again, the function should be called again. And you exactly when the data will arrive.

```js
export class UserService {
  private userModel: UserModel = new UserModel();

  getUserModel() {
    return this.userModel;
  }

  setUserModel(user) {
    this.userModel = user
  }
}
```

some.component.ts

```js
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  userModel: UserModel;

  constructor(private _userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // It's a one time call and you control when you get (or `pull`) the data
    this.userModel = this._userService.getUserModel();   
  }
}
```

#### Method 2: push based

Here the observable decides when you receive the data. This is the basic of reactive/asynchronous data flow. You subscribe to the data source and wait till it pushes the data. You have no knowledge when the result might arrive.

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  public userSubject$ = new Subject<any>();

  getUserModel() {
    return this.userSubject$.asObservable();
  }

  setUserModel(user) {
    this.userSubject$.next(this.userModel = user);
  }
}
```

some.component.ts

```js
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  userModel: UserModel;
  closed$ = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(private _userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // The stream is open until closed and the service/observable decide when it sends (or `pushes`) the data
    this._userService.getUserModel().pipe(   
      takeUntil(this.closed$)                // <-- close the `getUserModel()` subscription when `this.closed$` is complete
    ).subscribe(
      userModel => { this.userModel = userModel }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.closed$.next();
    this.closed$.complete();
  }
}
```

Angular uses observables extensively due to the nature of data flow in a typical web-application and the flexibility it provides.

For eg. the HTTP client returns an observable that you can latch on to and wait till the server returns any information. And the RxJS provides numerous [operators and functions](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api) to refine and adjust the data flow.

Comment: I know the two approaches but my doubt is just used observable for HTTP function? In this situation it is not an HTTP function is just retrieving a populate object that I created after the user signing in my application and I want to know when to one above another understand?

Comment: @wavrik: HTTP function is an use case example. It depends on your needs, if you need the object only once a normal method would suffice. However if you either want to listen to the changes to the object everytime or if you want to mix the object with another asynchronous data stream then go with observables.

Answer (score 0):

If I could paraphrase your question(s), I'm guessing it'd go something like:

#### Why should I use Angular Services instead of just making async/http calls directly from the component?/Why should I write Service logic in a separate file as a dependency?

*and*

#### Why should I use lifecycle methods like **ngOnInit** and **ngOnDestroy** in conjunction with Services or async/http calls?

When it comes to questions like these, the Angular framework is more opinionated than other SPA technologies like React, Vue, etc. So while you're not technically forced to follow either of the approaches you listed, you should know of the downsides and problems that emerge if you follow the first approach rather than the traditional injectable Service approach(number 2).

Generally speaking, the Angular team recommends following a **unidirectional data flow** pattern in your app implemented with Services. This means that data flow should generally come from Services which distribute the data to components and then to view templates.

Within this pattern, there's also an implication of **separation of concerns** which is a good practice to follow within any app. Services should handle fetching and handling data, components should handle view logic, and templates should be as clean and declarative as possible. Components and their templates should consume data that's been processed already. Relatedly, you should try to keep your components as **pure** as possible - meaning they produce as few side effects as possible. This is because components are dynamically mounted and unmounted in the course of a user session. Have a look at [this article](https://medium.com/@jtomaszewski/how-to-write-good-composable-and-pure-components-in-angular-2-1756945c0f5b) for more information on pure components.

Aside from the above architectural discussion of Services there are some other, more concrete consequences to be aware of:

- Failure to unsubscribe from observables can lead to memory leaks in your application. With the first scenario you've outlined above, a component may be loaded 10-20 times in a user session and each time you're setting up a new subscription without tearing it down again. This can have a very real performance impact on your app.
- The Angular compiler is optimized to add and remove dependencies dynamically, resulting in better app performance. If you keep all your Service code right in your component, they'll be larger and slower. From a UX perspective, components should be as light and nimble as possible so they can load quickly for the user.
- If you register a service as a provider, the Angular compiler will treat it as a **singleton** meaning there can be only one instance of it. This is as opposed to the many instances of a Service class generated with each component if you were to use the first approach you listed. This is another performance benefit of using injectable Services.

The Angular compiler is optimized to work with the DI framework so your next step may be to learn more about it and the implications of going with one approach or the other. There's a long [talk about creating your own Angular Compiler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQ2plVD0gDI) that's a couple years old now that might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but about your first question, if you see is not an async HTTP request it is just returning an object and I can return like the function from a service or as a subject, but the problem is when I make a variable like this this.userModel = this.UserService.getUserModel(), if I change this.userModel.name the entire app will not update because the variable don't reference it is just cloning.

Comment: Oh okay, it looks like I haven't fully understood your issue here. At this point, I'm not sure what you're trying to do yet but if you're wanting share a User object in your app with RxJS Subject then you just need to pass a modified User object to the Subject's next() method. You can't just do this.userModel = this.UserService.getUserModel(). 

Simply put, for retrieving the User data, always set up a subscription to a subject, and for pushing new User data, pass it through the .next() method.

Comment: Note that with the code you've shown, your first approach's getUserModel() is not making use of observables. 
Also, you should go with using a Service to hold that Subject since there will only be a single instance of that Service as mentioned above.